# Ajax fails when called within a function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, raspbian

When I call Ajax in the main body of Jquery code, it returns the correct result, but when I call it from within a function, it fails.  Here is the server side code:

```html
    <?php
    $what       = $_POST["what"];
    $where      = $_POST["where"];

    if(isset($what)){
        $data = array(
            "what"      => $what,
            "where"     => $where,
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    ?>
```

Here is the code that succeeds (returns text to the browser):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            what = "dog";
            where = "in the manger";

            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {what : what, where : where},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                    error: function (error)
                {
                    alert("ajax error ");
                }
            });

            </script>
        </head>
        <body> <div id="result"></div> </body>
    </html>
```

and here is the code that fails (alerts "error"):
`

```js
    <html>
    <head>
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            what = "dog";
            where = "in the manger";

            function get_click () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {what : what, where : where},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $("#result1").text(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function (error)
                {
                    alert("ajax error " + JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="result1"></div> </body>
        <form onsubmit="get_click()">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to make the function-wrapped Ajax call work because I need to process  data from a form before sending it to the server.  What am I doing wrongly?

The environment is a headless Raspberry Pi with Raspbian os, FireFox browser on Windows 10.

Comment: I see several problems to start.   1) You are linking jquery twice.  2) one of your jquery links is above the html opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears likely that the reason you don't see any text in the browser is that you are submitting a form and you are not blocking the default action of the form submission.  This will cause the ajax call to be sent, but then the page will immediately reload and the result of the ajax call will not be displayed.

To fix this, you would call `e.preventDefault()` in your event handler.

```
function get_click(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {what : what, where : where},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result1").text(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("ajax error " + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

And, add the event parameter to your HTML:

```
   <form onsubmit="get_click(event)">
        <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/841v9rpf/.  If you remove the `e.preventDefault()` from the demo, then the form submits.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much, jfriend.